# Cómo agregar un tipo de publicación personalizada a WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Tengo un custom post type con el tipo "Servicios" y necesito pasarlo por el carrito de woocommerce pero este solo acepta el post type de "product".

existe alguna forma de que el carrito o woocommerce acepte otros post type, ya he visto [Agregar tipo de publicación personalizada / publicación a Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548188/adding-custom-post-type-post-to-woocommerce) pero no ofrece una respuesta funcional actualmente.

Answer (score 2):

Vamos más atrás.
Wordpress acepta muchos tipos de posts mediante taxonomíás. El producto es una taxonomía que WooCommerce instala por defecto. Una taxonomía admite atributos (en un post normal, tags o categorías). Puedes hacer que esos tags o categorías tengan su clasificación y paginación. Los custom post types son lo mismo.

Tú quieres tomar woocommerce y añadir un primo paralelo de productos, y pienso que aunque se puede es algo de alta dificultad y bastante frágil, que pasaría por hacer un plugin hijo de WooCommerce que sustituya todas las *funciones* que hoy traen un producto de la BBDD (y lamentablemente son funciones, en su mayor parte no son clases y las que hay no respetan PSR-4).

**Edit 1: Respecto del link que pusiste**

> ya he visto [Agregar tipo de publicación personalizada / publicación a
> Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548188/adding-custom-post-type-post-to-woocommerce) pero no ofrece una respuesta funcional actualmente.

Solamente propone que si no tienes woocommerce puedes registrar el custom post type "product" y cuando instales WooCommerce debiera tomarlos como tal.

**Pero no todo está perdido**

Tu pregunta empieza diciendo **qué** quieres hacer

> Tengo un custom post type con el tipo "Servicios" y necesito pasarlo por > el carrito de woocommerce pero este solo acepta el post type de "product".

Y en concreto preguntas el **cómo** hacer algo que solucionaría el **qué**.

> existe alguna forma de que el carrito o woocommerce acepte otros post type?

Como empecé diciendo, el cómo que estás preguntando es un problema y fuera de hacer una prueba de concepto creo que no vale la pena embarcarse en ese camino. Hay más de un **cómo** y depende del flujo final que quieres habilitar en tu tienda.

**Edit2: Solución posible.**

Los productos soportan modificadores. Un servicio calificaría como un producto virtual, y si lo que vendes puede formularse como un voucher por un servicio, también podrías mapearlo a un producto descargable.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edit3: hay [atributos de producto personalizados](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-6) que puedes añadir al importar con un CSV o editando individualmente. Si tu custom post type tiene su razón de ser en que tiene otros campos, puedes añadirlos a tus productos de tipo servicio y dejarlos en blanco para los productos tangibles. Por ejemplo, si los servicios tienen un atributo "prestador" (o sea quien brinda el servicio) o la especialidad del tipo de servicio involucrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al importar te ofrecerá añadirlos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esos atributos puedes registrarlos como taxonomía tal que luego en portada puedas listarlos igual que una categoría. Por ejemplo puedes hacer el atributo "prestador", o "especialidad" que solamente tenga un valor definido para los servicios. Esto con poca modificación podría listarse en una url como

```
https://mitisio.com/prestador/pedro-perez
```

o

```
https://mitisio.com/especialidad/electricista
```

Los productos normales, si es que tienes, no aparecerán en esa vista, ni en ninguna especialidad o prestados, porque no tienen esos atributos (o los tienen vacíos, o N/A).

Comment: ¿Y con esas taxonomías podría pasar esos post al carrito? @ffflabs